# Excel Date/Time not correct within same data

Tags: excel, date, time

Minor thing and not sure if on the right place to ask.. but; I have a large dataset with dates, some of then have the correct date stamp, others are just a string of numbers and time which forms an optical date, but isn't. I figured out it has something today with a double space.

12/12/2016 13:01:32 PM

12/12/2016  12:33:46 PM  (this one has 2 spaced between 2016 and 12)

the last one is the correct format for a date stamp

[image]

research:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/502863-extract-am-pm-text-date-time.html

Comment: What does the time 13:01:32 PM mean? If you are using 24 hours time, then only 13:01:32 (without AM/PM) makes sense since it is 01:01:32 PM. But 13:01:32 PM is nonsense.

Comment: indeed, so i don't know why its even in there, I think the issue lies with the data provider as it makes no sense maybe deleting the PM will help

Comment: Got it, the problem was in the data set.. with text to column I separated the date time and PM/AM.. then I can get the date and time separate and delete the last column.. thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0):

Got it, the problem was in the data set.. with text to column I separated the date time and PM/AM.. then I can get the date and time separate and delete the last column.. thanks for your interest